# Are There Any Tools For Updating Javadoc Automatically?

Tags: java, javadoc

I work on a code base that is ... messy.  One aspect of this messiness is that we have a ton of methods whose signatures no longer match the associated Javadoc.  For instance:

```
/**
 *
 * @ param foo
 */
public void doFoo(int bar) {...
```

I'm no fan of generated Javadoc (as it's almost always worthless), but I really could use a tool that would go through our code, find cases like that, and:

1. remove the javadoc for the "foo" param
2. add javadoc for the "bar" param (but just a blank one, no auto-generated doc or anything)

Does such a tool exist?  If not, does a tool that just does #1 exist?  Even that much would significantly reduce the amount of garbage warnings we get in our builds.  Thanks.

Comment: P.S. I did try searching for a question like this in SO already (as I expected that there would have been one), but after wading through several hundred questions I still came up with nothing, so ... new question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetBeans has a tool for that. It does exactly what you ask.

You can either click on the `Tools` Menu, then `Analyze Javadocs` from the top,
or right click on a file and click `Tools`, then `Analyze Javadocs`.

This then give you a list of all problems it finds with your Javadocs with an option to fix it. It allows you to fix a single problem in a method, fix the javadocs for the method, for the file, for the package, or for the entire project.

Comment: By default (at least in **Netbeans 8.0.2**) this tool **will not** find errors in JavaDoc in private methods. In order to change the scope of **Analyze Javadoc** go to `Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Hints -> JavaDoc -> Error in Javadoc -> Scope` and change the scope to private.

Answer (score 3):

One solution, if you're using eclipse, is to go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Javadoc`
and then set the 'Malformed Javadoc comments' variable to warning or error.

You can then go to the problems view `Window -> Show View -> Problems` and then on each error right click and select 'Quick Fix'.

Comment: I tried this (although I marked the NetBeans solution as the answer, because it seems more powerful, I personally am an Eclipse user).  However, none of the warnings show up in problems :-(  When I view one of them, it has a yellow squiggly line underneath it, but even when I tell Eclipse to validate that file, I still get nothing in the problems window.   Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried any of these other than DocCheck, but [this somewhat-dated page on Sun's site](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/faq/) lists several third-party doclets, some of which purport to insert Javadoc into your source.  Of those, you might take a look at [Doc-o-Matic](http://www.doc-o-matic.com/), [JRefactory Pretty Printer](http://jrefactory.sourceforge.net/cspretty.html), and [ACTOS Auto Commentator for Java](http://www.actos-lab.com/AC4J.html).  Again, I have not tried any of these, but it's a place to start.