# Is a tool to add javadoc comments from the method declarations

Tags: java, javadoc

I am wondering there is any tool can generate the javadoc's comment from the method declarations etc?

Comment: Many popular IDE's have this built-in (Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans). Of course, they do not explain what the method does, but return type, parameters and any thrown exceptions are automatically filled out for you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862406/are-there-any-tools-for-updating-javadoc-automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JAutodoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/) is an Eclipse plugin that has this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

As @Bart commented, popular IDEs can generate the Javadoc skeleton from your method declaration. However, the content you have to fill in yourself. And you would better - in fact, it is better to have no Javadoc than to have loads of autogenerated Javadoc containing no useful (or even worse, obsolete) information. So please be careful when (ab)using your IDE to autogenerate Javadoc...

Comment: I cannot find in the Eclipse, requires plugin. I am using 3.6

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Eclipse and NetBeans both have facilities to do this. They just generate the outline, of course, no actual description of anything.

Comment: I cannot find in the Eclipse, requires plugin. I am using 3.6.